# Python function that would take input into 64 bit and then change to 8bytes output

Tags: python, byte, bit

I want to be able to input a series of numbers that respresent a bit in a 64bit..then reverse it and display 8 bytes. I been lookint at bitstring but haven't gotten to output what I am expecting.

## code

```
def Pconvert(*varloadID):
  bits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
  for x in varloadID:
      x -= 1
      bits[x] = 1
  print bits
  
  j = int(''.join(map(str, bits)))
  print j
```

## input

```
Pconvert(1,8,64)
```

## expecting list

```
[129,0,0,0,0,0,0,128]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do what you're looking for:

```
def Pconvert(*varloadID):
  bits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
  for x in varloadID:
    bits[x-1] = 1
  print bits

  bytes = [bits[i*8:i*8+8] for i in xrange(0,8)]
  return map(lambda byte: int(''.join(map(str,byte)),2),bytes)

print Pconvert(1,8,64)
```

Some notes:

1. You somehow have to break your 64 bits into 8 segments, the `bytes` variable here.
2. You need to pass the base when it's not `10` (in this case, `2`) when calling `int`.
3. I think the 8th element should be `1` not `128`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct

def Pconvert(*varloadID):
    bits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
    for x in varloadID:
        x -= 1
        bits[x] = 1
    j = int(''.join(map(str, bits)), 2)
    print(j)
    bytestr = struct.pack('>Q', j).decode('cp1252')
    a = list()
    for i in bytestr:
        a.append(ord(i))
    print(a.__len__())
    return a
```

using struct have faster run time than the other solution

Comment: Don't post link-only answers in case the links become obsolete. You should summarise its relevant contents here so that your answer is independent and provide the link for credits or further reading.